# Update log appears on booting

Tags: boot, grub2

When i boot my laptop into Ubuntu, device drivers update log is showing on the screen.

How can I boot into Ubuntu, without seeing these errors and logs?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you, but you can activate the splash bootscreen while booting Ubuntu, by editing the file `/etc/default/grub` (for example you could run `sudoedit /etc/default/grub`) and setting

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

After changing this setting you need to upgrade grub with

```
sudo update-grub2
```